# RuntimeBinderException on inherited interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, dynamic, interface

I am getting a RuntimebinderException when calling a inherited method of an interface passing a dynamic as one of the arguments.

I do not understand this behaviour.

Here is a complete example:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic dyn = new Record();

        IAdvancedTable advTable = new Table();
        ITable table = advTable;

        // works like a charm using the "base-interface"
        table.Insert(dyn);


        // using the inherited interface throws the RuntimeBinderException
        advTable.Insert(dyn);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public interface ITable
{
    void Insert(Record record);
}

public interface IAdvancedTable : ITable{}

public class Table : IAdvancedTable
{
    public void Insert(Record record){ /*STUB*/ }
}

public class Record{}
```

Looks like that there is no recursion in the RuntimeBinder checking for "inherited interfaces" on the actual interface. But is there any reason for this?

Comment: This feels like a bug to me... the members of `IAdvancedTable` should include the inherited ones. (That said, this area of the spec can be subtle.) I suggest you raise an issue on https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn (It's worth noting that if you change `dyn` to be statically typed to record, it all compiles...)

Comment: @JonSkeet It soothes me that you think this is a bug. This caused quite an issue for us. I will wait a bit to see if one of the Micorsoft Guys here will respond to this and if not, ill raise the issue like you suggested.

Comment: "Looks like that there is no recursion in the RuntimeBinder checking for "inherited interfaces" on the actual interface" is skewing the issue a bit. it is likely in that recursive check that the actual type of your dynamic is not being account for. Workaround is to cast dyn: `advTable.Insert((dyn as Record))` or `advTable.Insert((Record)dyn)`